# Sencha Architect create override

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-architect

I want to create an override for the Ext.MessageBox. I have created the override file manually and pointed a JS resource to it. Now Architect sees this file as an override. 
But when calling the override function I get an error. If I look throught the Ext.MessageBox object the new function is not there. How can I specify overrides in Architect? What excactly am I doing Wrong?

**/app/overrides/MessageBox.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.override.MessageBox', {
    override: 'Ext.MessageBox',

    test: function(){
        alert("123");
}

});
```

**calling**: `Ext.MessageBox.test();`

**gives**: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'test'`

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox is a singleton which you cannot override in this way.

You can add things to MessageBox in code like so:

Ext.MessageBox.test = function() { alert('123'); });